# Get destination node in Angular UI Tree

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I'm using [Angular UI Tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) as the UI for a file system.  I want to be able to drop items into folders but not files so all the items in the tree have a type property with values "file" or "folder".

How can I check this property and either allow or disallow items to be dropped in depending on the value?  I've tried adding a check in the accept callback.  sourceNodeScope gives me the type of the node I'm moving in `sourceNodeScope.$modelValue.type` but `destNodesScope.$modelValue` seems to alternate between the item I'm moving and the destination.  And when it is the destination, it's an array of all the nodes at that level in the tree.

```
accept: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the beforeDrop method rather than accept. The dest on the event can be used to check the destination and should return true if the drop is allowed.

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
  beforeDrop: function (e) {
    var destValue = e.dest.nodesScope.node ? e.dest.nodesScope.node.type : undefined

    if (destValue === 'file') {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```